# How to understand if unless combination in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm reading the official rails 4 guide   [in this section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#callback-registration)  . there are some conditional  statements i don't understand .    [This post helps me understand most cases](http://www.codecademy.com/glossary/ruby/if-unless-elsif-and-else#unless) but i get confused with the following example:

```
def ensure_login_has_a_value
    if login.nil?
            self.login = email unless email.blank?
   end
end
```

**I understand it in this way**  : if `login.nil?` return true. code `self.login = email` get executed, if  `email.blank?` return true . it does nothing.

However when i look at this code :

```
before_create do
    self.name = login.capitalize if name.blank?
```

i have no idea why **if conditional statement** is there ?

When you encounter with this kind of issue , what would you do instead of asking on stackoverflow?

Comment: do some simple test in a ruby console to see how it works

Comment: I think it would be clearer for the author to have written, `self.login = email if login.nil? && !email.blank?`. btw, since your question has nothing to do with callbacks, you should make no mention of them in your question. Nobody cares if this came up while you were researching callbacks or having lunch at Oscar's.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland  just edited the question. Thank you for your suggestion .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with this:

```
before_create do
  self.name = login.capitalize if name.blank?
end
```

if it was simply like this:

```
before_create do
  self.name = login.capitalize
end
```

then the `name` would always be overwritten by `login.capitalize`.  Instead, we only want to set the name equal to the login if the name isn't set.  So it's like saying "the default value for name is the capitalized version of the login".

The first bit of code is quite confusingly written and a bit clumsy.  I would rewrite it thus:

```
def ensure_login_has_a_value
  if self.login.blank? && !self.email.blank?
    self.login = self.email
  end
end
```

which i think is a bit more readable.

Answer (score 2):

I would rewrite your code blocks of `ensure_login_has_a_value` like this:

```
def ensure_login_has_a_value
    if !login.present? && email.present?
       self.login = email 
   end
end
```

Now try to read the condition:
If login not present and email present then assign email to login attributes.

As long as you can read your code, your code is awesome.

Well this is against your code format.